RxJS alternative to debounceTime operator, so items won't get collected?
RxJS pros out there, I need your help!
Based on my last question I'm now looking for something different:

Question: How to separate values of a stream, keep the last of each and force flush after a certain time?

I have a solution which works totally fine, but it doesn't feel right / optimized.
This is my current solution in two steps.
Step 1 preparation: obs$ fires random numbers at random every 100 miliseconds
    const list = [1,1,1,1,3];
    const obs$ = timer(0, 100)
      .pipe(take(list.length))
      .pipe(map(x => list[x]));
  
   // => 1 - [100ms] - 1 - [100ms] - 1 - [100ms] - 1 - [100ms] - 3

Step 2: split by number, collect data, flush after 300ms
obs$.pipe(
   map((x, idx) => ({item: x, idx})),            // debug #1 
   tap(x => console.log(x.idx + ": " + x.item)), // debug #2 
   groupBy(x => x.item),
      mergeMap(grouped => 
         grouped.pipe(bufferTime(300), filter((x) => !!x.length), map(x => x[x.length-1])) // ⚠️ the ugly part
      )
   )
  .subscribe(x => console.log("✅" + x.idx + ": " + x.item));

Result
0 => 1
1 => 1
2 => 1
✅ 2 => 1
3 => 1
4 => 1
✅ 3 => 1
✅ 4 => 3

It works! We got always the last value of kind and additionally one value every 300ms!
Even though it does the job, it has two downfalls:

"⚠️ the ugly part" is ugly. Feels like there has to be an alternative.
bufferTime() "collects" data even though the data is always the same. E.g. here it saved [1,1,1].

So, is there an leaner way to achieve the same?
Note: grouped.pipe(debounceTime(300)) won't do the same as my code. It won't output "✅ 2 => 1" because the value 1 keeps coming in. So basically I'm looking for a debounce with a "forced flush every x seconds".
Thanks in advance for diving in!
Stackblitz

After some research I found out that throttleTime() does the job here.
// grouped.pipe(bufferTime(300), filter((x) => !!x.length), map(x => x[x.length-1])) // ⚠️ the ugly part
// replaced with:
throttleTime(300, undefined, { leading: false, trailing: true })

throttleTime() pipes the first and/or last value (leading/trailing) in a given time span. Because the pipe before already grouped all values we luckily don't need to care of the values - it's always the same.
Note:
For our purpose we also have to set "{ leading = false, trailing = true }" so we can always count on getting the last proc of a value. The default value for this 3rd parameter is "{ leading = true, trailing = false }".
